# Angular JQuery Datepicker Not Setting MinDate on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I'm using JQuery UI's Datepicker on Date From and Date To fields in an AngularJS project.  I've added the directive to bind the value to the model value, and I've also added a check to OnSelect that sets the minDate and maxDate options for each field (so the Date To is never earlier than the Date From).  The problem is that, on loading the page, no date has actually been selected (even though the model has a value), so it is still possible to select a To date earlier than the Date From.  I added a $watch service to at least correct the error, but I still can't figure out how to set the minDate on load either within the directive or inside the controller. I've also tried $(document).ready outside of the Angular code, but that isn't working either.  Here's my code prior to adding anything to set the minDate.

Within controller:

```
$scope.messagesForm.dateFrom = moment().subtract('days', 30).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
$scope.messagesForm.dateTo = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
$scope.$watch('messagesForm.dateTo', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal) return;
    if (Date.parse(newVal) < Date.parse($scope.messagesForm.dateFrom)) {
        $scope.messagesForm.dateFrom = newVal;
    }
});
```

Directive:

```
.directive('datepicker', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $(function(){
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                showStatus: true,
                showWeeks: true,
                highlightWeek: true,
                maxDate: 0,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showAnim: "scale",
                showOptions: { origin: ["bottom", "right"] },
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    if (this.id === "MessageDateFrom") {
                       $("#MessageDateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
                    } else if (this.id === "MessageDateTo") {
                        $("#MessageDateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                    }
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" id="MessageDateFrom" class="form-control dates" ng-model="messagesForm.dateFrom" datepicker readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" id="MessageDateTo" class="form-control dates" ng-model="messagesForm.dateTo" datepicker readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Failing JQuery I've attempted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("MessageDateTo").datepicker("option","minDate",$("MessageDateFrom").val());
};
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plunker/fiddle for this?

Comment: No, I'll try to put one together.

Comment: This has all the relevant code and libraries but for some reason Plunker is not processing the JS file correctly. http://plnkr.co/edit/cvVSoYJuAz1gk0Pst9wN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to worries about when controller loads or what just add this two property which is [**minDate**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) & [**maxDate**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) with there limit like `minDate:"-30d",maxDate: 0,`

You also can place minDate and maxDate values dynamically from directive property.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    showStatus: true,
                    showWeeks: true,
                    highlightWeek: true,
                    minDate:"-30d", //here i did logic -30d
                    maxDate: 0, //today is max date
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    showAnim: "scale",
                    showOptions: { origin: ["bottom", "right"] },
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cq0fgYgr0i1roRAmBS11?p=preview)**

**Update**

Sorry for my wrong assumption, If you really do care about whenever the data gets loaded or date variable are assigned at that time `jquery ui datepicker` should bind to them, then I'll prefer to use `attrs.$observe` which will gets call whenever your attribute expression gets evaluated. For make it working I did added one attribute name `loaded="{{messagesForm.dateFrom}}"` & `loaded="{{messagesForm.dateTo}}"` on the page so whenever the value gets assigned to dateFrom and dateTo the respective datepicker will get assign to their elements

**Directive**

```
 app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            //get called when `{{}}` value evaluated
            attrs.$observe('loaded',function(val){
              element.datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                  showStatus: true,
                  showWeeks: true,
                  highlightWeek: true,
                  maxDate: 0,
                  numberOfMonths: 1,
                  showAnim: "scale",
                  showOptions: { origin: ["bottom", "right"] },
                  onSelect: function (date) {
                      if (this.id === "MessageDateFrom") {
                         $("#MessageDateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
                      } else if (this.id === "MessageDateTo") {
                          $("#MessageDateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                      }
                      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                      scope.$apply();
                  }
              });
            })

        }
    }
});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HMJcGeT1mzJo0h3xJeMg?p=preview) with demonstration of setting value of scope variables after 5 sec.

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want the minDate on the DateFrom to be limited to 30 days back, only the DateTo, and only on initial load. After the initial load, I need the DateFrom and DateTo to update each other's min and max dates dynamically. Where can I set the individual options? Whenever I try to do it with JQuery it doesn't seem to work because of the Angular directive conflicting.

Comment: I actually think $timeout was the answer in conjunction with your other suggestions, so thanks for that.  Check out an updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/BmM1YgvpT2kioSg5smq4?p=preview

Comment: @spjpdx doing DOM manipulation from controller is antipattern  in angular https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns..please don't to that either use `attr.$observe`/`$timeout`/`scope.$evalAsync`

Answer (score 0):

update the `minDate` and `maxDate` in `$timeout`.

`$timeout` will make sure that the directive is rendered.

Here is the updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/2ucTcwKFPFpgxoJiRB3f?p=preview

Comment: please check he want to change min and max date dynamically..and what you mentioned.I already fixed it..

Comment: @pankajparkar, I overlooked it. Thanks for that. Updated the plunker.

Comment: please confirm it yourself first..refer comment in my answer

Comment: He handled that logic in the onSelect.