# Jquery datepicker with angular returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

In one Form I'm developing using angular, i use two datepickers

```html
 <td><input  ng-model="reportsVal.start_date" type="text" id="startDatePicker"  ng-disabled="showVals"></td>
  <td><input  ng-model="reportsVal.end_date" type="text" id="endDatePicker" required ng-disabled="showVals"></td>
```

```js
 $( "#startDatePicker").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     

     buttonImage : "images/icons/calender.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Start Date",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: dateToday,
        numberOfMonths: 1
       
       
    });
    $( "#endDatePicker").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     

     buttonImage : "images/icons/calender.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "End Date",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: dateToday
       
    });
```

on submit when i console log **reportsVal.start_date** and **reportsVal.end_date** it comes as expected. But when i use end_date must be greater than start_date condition like below

```js
   $( "#startDatePicker").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     

     buttonImage : "images/icons/calender.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Start Date",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: dateToday,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
         var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
         if (date) {
         date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
         }
         $("#endDatePicker").datepicker("option","minDate", date)
         } 
       
    });
    $( "#endDatePicker").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     

     buttonImage : "images/icons/calender.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "End Date",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: dateToday,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
            }
            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker("option","maxDate", date || 0)
            } 
    });
```

i'm getting **undefined** for these values **reportsVal.start_date** and **reportsVal.end_date**

Comment: you should wrap plugin code in directive, to map changed value correctly with `ng-model`, look into [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28753101/2435473) would help you.

Comment: You are on a very wrong track. Advice: remove jQuery from the project until you understand really well *why* you don't need it.