# Unable to bind the Calendar value in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am new in angular js and trying to bind the value of calendar date from the jquery calendar picker but it is not binding accept the date all other fields are binding.

Here is my HTML

```
<input id="company" name="company"  ng-model="user.company"  type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" required>

<input type="text"  name="exdate" ng-model="user.exdate"  id="exiprydate" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" required>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$(function () {
               $("#exiprydate").datepicker({                        
                      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                    });
                });
```

Here is my Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('adminController', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.submitloginform = function(isValid, user) {
        console.log($scope.user);
    });
```

Here is the snap of calendar by which i can pick the date :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F72wJ.png)

Comment: I would suggest that you create a angular directive for the datepicker and you will be able to set the ng-model in there and you will be able to set the value of selected date in there. That's how I have done this in the past.

Comment: Create a wrapper directive like shown here in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749331/angular-jquery-datepicker-not-setting-mindate-on-load)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a directive for the datepicker.. something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datePicker', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   require: 'ngModel',
   scope: {
        ngModel: '='
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            onSelect: function(date) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
            }
        });
   }
  };
});
```

and your HTML will be:

```
<input date-picker type="text" ng-model="myDate" />
```