# How to bind Datepicker with angular ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a form with a few fields in HTML. Below is the related lines for the date fields where I use a datepicker.

```
<input tabindex="3" class="date-picker" name = "startDate" type="text" id="startDate" ng-model = "startDate" ng-required="true">
<input tabindex="4" class="date-picker" name = "endDate" type="text" id="endDate" ng-model = "endDate" ng-required="true">
```

Here is the javascript for the datepicker.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });
```

and Here is the Angular JS controller for the form. I'm sending a REST request to my backend and taking the response.

```
tournamentAddApp.controller('tournamentAddController', function ($scope, $window, $http) {

$scope.controller = "tournamentAddController";    

$scope.add = function () {
    var data = {
                name: $scope.tournamentName,
                location: $scope.location,
                status: $scope.status,
                description: $scope.description,
                startDate: $scope.startDate,
                endDate: $scope.endDate             

            };
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/crickmaster-app-userapp/controller/tournament/create";

    $http.post(url, data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //console.log(data);
    $window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
});
```

However when I submit the form, JSON header doesn't contain the **date** fields. It contain all other fields but not the date fields. In other words when I submit the form, non of the data goes to the database. After doing some research I feel like this has to do with the binding of the datepicker. I've referred the below post and tried suggested solutions but it doesn't contain a clear answer so therefore I might be doing something wrong.

**[how to bind Bootstrap-datepicker element with angularjs ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/how-to-bind-bootstrap-datepicker-element-with-angularjs-ng-model)**

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28753101/2435473) for jquery-ui datepicker binded via directive

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is

```
 var data = {
                name: $scope.tournamentName,
                location: $scope.location,
                status: $scope.status,
                description: $scope.description,
                startDate: $scope.startDate,
                endDate: $scope.endDate             
            };
```

the startDate is inside the data. 
so I suggest you to add these **before** the declaration of data in the controller

```
$scope.startDate="";
$scope.endDate ="";
```

Instead, Angular UI Bootstrap can make your work simple at this [LINK](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Use this

**HTML**

```
<p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
```

Add this to your controller

```
 $scope.dt = new Date();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion by adding those two lines before the declaration of data. Now request body contains both dates but they are empty. For example it'd look something like this.

Comment: "description":"test","name":"test","location":"test","startDate":"","endDate":""

Answer (score 0):

For this better to create a directive, as the value you set doesn't reflect in **ng-model** because its outside of **scope**, so for this you can Inject the module in your app e.g. `angular.module('App', ['cjqDatepickerModule'])`.

Then use it in HTML like:

```
<div cjq-datepicker dateformat="dd-mm-yy"></div>;
angular
  .module("cjqDatepickerModule", [])
  .directive("cjqDatepicker", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var config = {};
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.dateformat)) {
          config.dateFormat = attrs.dateformat;
        }
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.mindate)) {
          config.minDate = attrs.mindate;
        }
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.maxdate)) {
          config.maxDate = attrs.maxdate;
        }
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.changemonth)) {
          config.changeMonth = true;
        }
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.changeyear)) {
          config.changeYear = true;
        }

        config.onClose = function (selected, jqueryDateInstance) {
          var expression = attrs.ngModel + " = " + "'" + selected + "'";
          scope.$apply(expression);
        };
        $(element).datepicker(config);
      },
    };
  });
```

Comment: So in the two HTML lines in my question, **cjq-datepicker dateformat="dd-mm-yy"** is needed to be added?

Comment: and rest of the code in your answer should be added to the controller right?